# Restart docker-compose containers on different host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My problem is not to deploy or build the container with docker-compose. I can easily build and deploy the container. However one remote server, the program will stop running at 18.00 (exit). I then want to restart it in the morning to do the fetching again. How do I do that without accessing from the build computer? All tutorials seems to assume that the container will run forever with restarts only by failure.

I am using

```
DOCKER_HOST="ssh://xxx@192.168.0.xx" docker-compose up -d
```

However this is from the dev machine. Since this is starting 3 different services I need a docker-compose on the server to start them in the same network. So I cannot rely on the one on the dev machine. Of course I can start each of them with docker run. But that would not give them a common network like with docker-compose.

Edit:
After searching the net for a while. It seems like it's hard to accomplish what I am trying to do. You should instead setup a local registry on the server (or somewhere). Then push images to this and setup a server docker-compose to start the images that where pushed to the registry.

[Link to deploying a local registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)

Comment: Why not put the docker-compose.yml file on the server and start it from there?

Comment: I assume it will then need access to the dev computer? I only need to start the same containers again.

Comment: define cron jobs maybe!

Comment: Tried the cronjob. But it doesn't work since docker-compose do not let you specify container name. So on every rebuild the script needs to change.